AndroidManifest.xml not found in package flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle
I'm facing a weird issue. Everything was working ok in my project until changing between branches.
After this I couldn't run it successful anymore.
The issue now when I try to run the app is:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
    > com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/diego/Projects/flutter/app/build/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle/intermediates/merged_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)

I don't have the package "flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle" explicity defined in my pubspec.yaml, but the package "camera" does have it as a dependency.
command fvm flutter pub deps
├── camera 0.11.0+2
│   ├── camera_android_camerax 0.6.8+2
│   │   ├── async...
│   │   ├── camera_platform_interface...
│   │   ├── flutter...
│   │   ├── meta...
│   │   └── stream_transform...
│   ├── camera_avfoundation 0.9.17+3
│   │   ├── camera_platform_interface...
│   │   ├── flutter...
│   │   └── stream_transform...
│   ├── camera_platform_interface 2.8.0
│   │   ├── cross_file 0.3.4+2
│   │   │   ├── meta...
│   │   │   └── web...
│   │   ├── flutter...
│   │   ├── plugin_platform_interface...
│   │   └── stream_transform...
│   ├── camera_web 0.3.5
│   │   ├── camera_platform_interface...
│   │   ├── flutter...
│   │   ├── flutter_web_plugins...
│   │   ├── stream_transform...
│   │   └── web...
│   ├── flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle 2.0.22
│   │   └── flutter...
│   └── flutter...

I tried many solutions:

Changing the camera version package
Changing the version of jdk
Changing of gradle version in build.gradle
Changing flutter version

I search
Does anyone have a suggestion of how can I solve this?
